# How can I resolve a MS teams bot - 403 error "Forbidden" status code that only appears for some tenants?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a personal app published in MS Teams App Source. This app includes a one-way bot that sends messages to Teams users that use the app.

Previously we provided this app to our customers via a sideloaded manifest.

MS global admin connects via our SaaS platform and completes the permission consent flow on behalf of all users.

Now all of our customers are using the published app. **For only 2 of our customers, all bot messages are failing**. We are getting the following error:

**"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException
Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"**

In the teams bot channel we see this warning: **"The tenant admin disabled this bot"**

We have checked the Teams Admin configuration and the app is assigned to a policy that allows the app for those users. The users are able to access and use the app, but just the bot messages are being blocked.

We use one app id and secret id for all our customers. The bot messages work for all other customers (and ourselves) except 2 customers.

Do you have any ideas how we can resolve this?

Comment: Did you find an answer and solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Since only 2 users have this error, it should not be a bug for the whole settings.

Two things you may want to check:

1. App permissions in Teams.
   Please let the user check if there anything set as "OFF", like flowbot app.
   Please check if there any custom user policy.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies
2. Admin Settings
   Please check if there any special policy you made
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/admin-settings